# Congruency and eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$If$   $two$   $matrices$   $are$   $congruent$   $then$   $they$   $have$   $the$   $same$   $eigen$   $values$   $??$

I have tried solving it using definition of congruent  matrices taking eigen value but didn't  come up with a proper solution ... how to solve it ???

Comment: The closest to a true statement similar to this may be Sylvester's inertia theorem ...

Comment: Like we can prove Aand B are similar matrices then they have the same eigen values | B-kl | = | A-kI | where k is their eigen value .. is there any similr proof to prove | B-kl | is not equal to | A-kI

Comment: What is Sylvester's inertia theorem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong $\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{2&1\cr0&-1/2\cr}$ are congruent but the first one has $1$ and $-1$ as eigen values and the second one has $2$ and $-1/2$ as eigen values.

Comment: Thank you i was trying to prove it using general values .. is there any general solution ??

Comment: Even simpler(?) $I$ and $(2I)^TI(2I)=4I$ are congruent and have different eigenvalues

Comment: well it is a counter example, so your statement is false. And imagine that you find a matrix such as $A$ and $D$ are congruent thanks to the orthogonal matrix $P$ and have the same eigen values and $D$ is diagonal. If you multiply $D$ by $\lambda >0$ then you always have $\lambda D$ and $A$ congruent, so they almost never have the same eigen values.

Comment: Yes thats true .. what if D is not diagonal

Comment: I have no simple idea at the moment. But not that all the symetric matrices are congruent to a diagonal matrix qnd the diagonal matrices are dence in the spaces of all the matrices, so it is not a very specific case.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping 